# How to redirect to app when a link is clicked in gmail app?

Tags: android-studio, gmail, deep-linking

I am working on an app that will redirect the user to the app when he click on a link on the gmail app. How can I accomplish that in android studio using java?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Deep links docs: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Just a filter for specific URL patter in Manifest will do.